# Custom cursor not growing/scaling on hover (can't figure it out)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hellol,I have a code for a custom cursor, and the cursor, which is a ball/circle, was supposed to grow/scale when hovering over a link, if you see the code below, this function is there, but it is not working, does anyone know what's wrong? Thank you in advance. Note, I am unable to create a snippet here. The code is from codepen: https://codepen.io/clementGir/pen/RQqvQx

````
<div class="cursor">
    <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
        <svg height="30" width="30">
            <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
        <svg height="10" width="10">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    body .cursor {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    body .cursor__ball {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    body .cursor__ball circle {
        fill: #f7f8fa;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script>
    const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
    const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
    const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    // Listeners
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
        if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
        $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
        $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
    }

    // Move the cursor
    window.CP.exitedLoop(0); function onMouseMove(e) {
        TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
            x: e.clientX - 15,
            y: e.clientY - 15
        });

        TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
            x: e.clientX - 5,
            y: e.clientY - 7
        });
    }

    // Hover an element
    function onMouseHover() {
        TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
            scale: 4
        });
    }
    function onMouseHoverOut() {
        TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
            scale: 1
        });
    }
</script>```


Growing cursor on hovering a link.
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors)

Comment: You asked the same question less than a day ago: [Custom cursor not growing/scaling on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719210/custom-cursor-not-growing-scaling-on-hover)

Comment: Thank you. No, it doesn't. I am not using images.

Comment: Yes, didn't get any answer that could fix the issue. I am asking again...

Comment: Do I have to add a CSS, hoverable class? If so, which one?

Comment: Watch [this GIF](https://imgur.com/a/wXFtEsq), Doesn't the cursor get grow/scale when hovering the link? Or I do not get it right.

Comment: It does on codepen, not on my website. That's the problem. I don't know what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The codepen you are trying to copy links to external scripts and has been adapted to work inside codepen.

What I did to get the pen to work here (I think you only needed step 4):

1. For CSS & JS clicked down arrow top right, view compiled
2. Copy over all code
3. Settings>JS>External Scripts>Copy link into Stack Overflow snippet's external scripts
4. Removed 'window.CP' code junk which I assume is something to do with codepen and getting the window object of their sub-document

```js
const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable');

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
}

// Move the cursor
function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
    x: e.pageX - 15,
    y: e.pageY - 15 });

  TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
    x: e.pageX - 5,
    y: e.pageY - 7 });

}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 4 });

}
function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1 });

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #010101;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
}
body h1,
body p,
body a {
  color: #fff;
}
body a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
}
body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #f7f8fa;
}
body .left,
body .right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body .right {
  background: #fff;
}
body .right a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
body .right h1,
body .right p,
body .right a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
    <svg height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Check out this link:</p>
  <a class="hoverable">Hover meh</a>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Check out this link:</p>
  <a class="hoverable">Hover meh</a>
</div>
```